# Ler 10 números inteiros e obter o maior entre eles

Tags: python, python-3.x

Usando uma função, faça um programa que leia 10 números inteiros e imprima na tela o maior deles.  No caso de valores iguais, imprima qualquer um dos maiores.  Caso o maior número seja múltiplo do primeiro número `n` lido, imprima `n` na tela. Dez números inteiros, considere que o primeiro número lido nunca será 0.

Alguém pode me ajudar nessa questão? Ainda sou leigo em Python.

```
n = int(input())
b = int(input())
c = int(input())
d = int(input())
e = int(input())
f = int(input())
g = int(input())
h = int(input())
i = int(input())
j = int(input())

lista = [n,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j]

print (max(lista))
```

Comment: Em fazer a parte dos multiplos, e na parte de "dez numeros inteiros, considere o primeiro numero lido nuca seja 0"

Comment: estou inputando 10 variáveis, e depois fiz uma lista onde consegui fazer o python imprimir o numero maior

Comment: n = int(input())
b = int(input())
c = int(input())
d = int(input())
e = int(input())
f = int(input())
g = int(input())
h = int(input())
i = int(input())
j = int(input())

lista = [n,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j]

print (max(lista))

Comment: como faço multiplo do primeiro número??

Answer (score 3):

Outra forma seria:

```
# Define a função:
def exercicio():

    # Lista com os números lidos:
    numeros = []

    # Lê o primeiro número, garantindo que não seja zero:
    numero = 0
    while numero == 0:
        numero = int(input("Entre com o 1º número: "))
        if numero == 0:
            print("O 1º número não pode ser zero.")
    numeros.append(numero)

    # Lê os outros nove números:
    for i in range(9):
        numero = int(input("Entre com o %dº número: " % (i+2)))
        numeros.append(numero)

    # Obtém o maior valor e exibe-o na tela:
    maior = max(numeros)
    print("O maior valor é", maior)

    # Verifica se o maior valor é múltiplo do primeiro:
    multiplo = maior % numeros[0] == 0

    # Se for, exibe o primeiro valor na tela:
    if multiplo:
        print("O maior valor é múltiplo do primeiro, que é", numeros[0])

# Chama a função definida:
exercicio()
```

<sup>Veja funcionando em [Ideone](https://ideone.com/sQtvYD) | [Repl.it](https://repl.it/LpmV/0)</sup>

Acredito que com os comentários no código seja possível compreendê-lo. A leitura do primeiro valor foi feita de forma separada pois responde a condições diferentes dos outros valores.

Answer (score 2):

Inicialmente é necessário montar uma `função` :

```
def maxNum_input(): #declara a função
    list_num = [] #declara a lista que vai receber os números
    i = 0 # um contador(há outras formas de fazer)
    while i < 10: # o loop
        number = int(input("Digite um número diferente de 0: ")) # a entrada você pode criar algo para impedir que o usuário digite 0
        list_num.append(number) # adiciona cada entrada a lista
        i += 1 # incrementa o contador
    if (max(list_num) % list_num[0]) == 0: # verifica se é múltiplo
        print("O maior número é múltiplo de :",list_num[0])
    print(max(list_num)) # a saída   
maxNum_input() # a chamada da função
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado :)

Comment: @user92865 considere validar a resposta que acredita estar correta, clicando no incon verde abaixo das setas de avaliação da resposta, boa sorte.

Answer (score 0):

Poderia fazer dessa forma:

```
cont = 0
lista_numeros =[]
while cont != 10: #Para poder pegar 10 numeros
    numero = int(input('Digite um numero: '))
    lista_numeros.append(numero)
    cont = cont + 1

maior = max(lista_numeros) # O max retorna o numero máximo em uma lista
if maior % lista_numeros[0] == 0 :
     print ('É múltiplo')
else:
     print ('Não é múltiplo')
```

O operador '%' retorna o resto da divisão, dessa forma você pode testar se o maior número é divisível pelo primeiro.

Comment: haaa sim agora entendi.

Comment: Muito Obrigada pela ajuda :)

Comment: Embora o AP tenha supostamente, visto como correta sua resposta, há de se levar em consideração, a necessidade explícita de ser uma função.

Comment: teria de ser maior % lista_numeros [0]  == 0. 
Alterado

Answer (score -2):

`maior = menor = 0`
`for cont in range(0, 10):`
`num = int(input(f'Número {cont + 1}: '))`
`if cont == 0:`
`maior = num`
`menor = num`
`elif num > maior:`
`maior = num`
`elif num < menor:`
`menor = num`
`print(f'O maior número foi {maior}')`
`print(f'O menor número foi {menor}')`

Answer (score -5):

```
num = [] 

for v in range (0, 9):  #v está armazenando as iterações vindas da função range
    lista = input("Digite um número diferente de zero:")  # Aqui lista fica como string. 
    if (lista.isnumeric()) and int(lista) != 0:   #is numeric() vê se o valor é numerico
        lista = int(lista) #só depois de checar passo lista pra int 
        if v == 0: # Primeira iteração adiciona o valor em num de antemão
            num.append(lista)
        
        if lista > num[-1] : #os valores só são comparados se lista receber um numero  
            num.append(lista)
    
    else:
        print("Você digitou um valor não numerico ou inválido")
        
        
print(max(num))

if (max(num)) %num[0] == 0: # Confere se o maior numero é multiplo 
    print(num[0])
 
#dentro deste for as posições não precisam ser escritas como lista[v] 
#porque acima já se assume que v será o iterador
```

Se em qualquer momento o uso ou a necessidade de alguma linha de código trouxer dúvida, comente abaixo que estarei disposto a clarificar, já que eu usei algumas coisinhas especificas, tipo a função `range()` mas por enquanto basta dizer que range sempre trabalha dentro de um dado intervalo de numeros (parando no numero final -1)

Escolhi esse jeito pois ele é relativamente simples,limpo em termos de código e usa algumas funções que o Python permite.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Há vários caracteres para os quais `isnumeric` retorna `True` mas dão erro ao converter para `int`, [veja aqui](https://ideone.com/BjUfXE). O melhor seria fazer logo `int(entrada)` e capturar o `ValueError` para saber se não foi digitado um número (mais ou menos [assim](https://ideone.com/pMJ7Ph)). Outro ponto é que a condição `lista != 0` é testada antes de converter `lista` para número, então a condição sempre será verdadeira (pois naquele ponto, `lista` ainda é uma string)

Comment: Não tem porque declarar `lista = []` não usado em lugar algum. Não tem porque declara `v` em `for v in range (0, 10):` melhor usar um `_`. E o código não imprime o primeiro número caso o maior seja múltiplo desse.

Comment: @hkotsubo Obrigado por apontar as falhas obtidas, especialmente a do !=0, não tinha me dado conta. Com relação ao isnumeric sei que não é o mais exato, mas resolve a questão.

Comment: @augusto Nesse momento estou atualizando o código com relação as variaveis não usadas, mas não entendi o seu ponto com relação aos múltiplos, realizei diversos casos de teste e obtive resultados coerentes em todos, com multiplos e não multiplos. A questão se refere a printar o maior de todos.

Comment: Você leu a pergunta toda? O autor da pergunta escreveu *...Caso o maior número seja múltiplo do primeiro número n lido, imprima n na tela....*, analise as outras respostas.

Comment: Li e reli e esse detalhe passou despercebido, peço perdão, consertarei agora.

Comment: Eu lhe perdoo. Editeis e não erreis mais. :)

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133179/discussion-between-augusto-vasques-and-victor-mariano).